# Cannot access 2 DIM array in function C

Tags: c, arrays

i have this funny problem. I have been trying to find a way how to pass my 2DIM array into function and i am still failing pretty hard.

So i get sizeX and sizeY from another function, which is called after the array is loaded by user.

...

```
   int sizeX = surf->settings->x;   // getting one dimension of the array
   int sizeY = surf->settings->y;   // getting second dimension of the array
   int** mirrorArray[sizeX][sizeY]; // create 2DIM array (I think this is perhaps wrong?
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeX; i = i+1 ) {   // filling it up with some zeros
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++ ) {
        mirrorArray[i][j] = 0;

    }}

    readArray((int **)mirrorArray, sizeX, sizeY); // now i would like to read the array (also maybe a source of my problems?)
```

and this is my reading function

```
void readArray(int *p[], int m, int n) {

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i = i+1) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("p[%i][%i] = %i \n", i, j, p[i][j]);
            }
        }

}
```

I am really flustrated. I get the Segmentation faul (core dumped) even if i try to access the first element in my array :/
If i dont create the function and just use the reading algorith after filling the array up with zeros, everything works, but i really need to implement the function. Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong please? :) Thank you very much.

**I still cant figure it out, every response will be highly useful :)**

Comment: the declaration ` int** mirrorArray[sizeX][sizeY];` is a two dimensional array of double pointers to `int`. While readArray is accepting an array of pointers (or it can be seen as a two dimensional array of `int`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify number of rows and columns on your array parameter. The following is valid in C99:

```
void readArray(int m, int n, int p[m][n]);
```

Notice that I needed to put the array sizes before the array in this declaration. Now the function can be called as:

```
int sizeX = surf->settings->x;   // getting one dimension of the array
int sizeY = surf->settings->y;   // getting second dimension of the array
int mirrorArray[sizeX][sizeY]; // create 2DIM array
readArray(sizeX, sizeY, mirrorArray);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response :) It really makes sense, but i am getting error "use of parameter "m" outside function body". I guess g++ i am currently using cant work this out. Temporary i used #define to set the array size (i am 90% sure that 500x500 is going to be enough). It is stupid solution, but i cant "change compiler and this stuff" because it wouldnt work for my colleges.

Comment: @panuf: In your question's title and tag the language is said to be C; now you say you're using a C++ compiler. Make up your mind. Note that your colleagues can call C functions by using `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int** mirrorArray[sizeX][sizeY];
```

`mirrorArray` is an 2D array of pointer to pointers. What you need is -

```
int mirrorArray[sizeX][sizeY];
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i still get exactly the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the problem with the array access? Could it be the `surf` thing?

Answer (score 0):

The declaration is incorrect. It should read:

```
int mirrorArray[sizeX][sizeY]
```

Your function prototype is confusing. It would better to use:

```
void readArray(int p[][], int m, int n) {
```

or :

```
   void readArray(int** p, int m, int n) {
```

You seem to be uncomfortable with the pointer-array equivalence. You should read https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays, it will certainly put you back on track.

Comment: I am very uncomfortable with you refering to arrays and pointers as "equivalent".  They are not, although arrays will decay to pointers.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment, i really am confused by the array-pointer stuff :/

the first line "void readArray" you suggested wont compile :( And the second gives me the same error as before. (I am using g++ compiler).

At this point, i am even more lost :D

Comment: Kernighan tutorial (http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-tutor.html) : "*(y+i)  gives x[i]". Good enough for me when it comes to defining "equivalence", but whatever floats your boat, man.